# Index out of range on column from inner join condition

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2017

I am getting a index out of range error when trying to get a string value from a datareader. The column USER_ROLE which is the only column from a INNER JOIN condition.  It was working and for some reason has now started throwing this index out of range error.  I've verified the actual stored procedure works via SSMS and the column is being returned.

Below is the code for the stored procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_GetUsersLogonInformation]
(
    -- inactive = 0, active = 1, all = 2
    @active int = 2
)
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @whereClauseNeeded bit = 1
    DECLARE @whereClause nvarchar(100) = concat(' WHERE usr.ACTIVE = ', @active)
    DECLARE @sqlCmd nvarchar(max)= 'SELECT 
        usr.USER_PK,
        usr.PRINCIPAL_ID,
        usr.AA_USER_FK,
        usr.FIRST_NAME,
        usr.LAST_NAME,
        usr.[USER_NAME], 
        usr.EMAIL_ADDRESS, 
        usr.ACTIVE,
        usr.LV_USER_ROLE_FK,
        lvur.USER_ROLE,
        usr.CREATED_BY,
        usr.CREATED_SYSDATE
    FROM dbo.USERS usr
        INNER JOIN dbo.LV_USER_ROLES lvur ON lvur.LV_USER_ROLE_PK = usr.LV_USER_ROLE_FK'
    IF @active = 0 OR @active = 1
    BEGIN
        set @sqlCmd = concat(@sqlCmd, @whereClause)
    END

    EXEC sp_executesql @sqlCmd
END
```

the c# code retrieving the data

```
using (SqlConnection dbConn = theVoiceSqlHelpers.GetDbConnection())
{
    using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(USP_GET_USER_INFO, dbConn))
    {
        sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@whereClause",string.Format("USER_NAME = \'{0}\'", txbxUserName.Text));

        SqlDataReader dr = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            user = new Tbl_Users();

            user.USER_PK = dr.GetInt32(dr.GetOrdinal("USER_PK"));
            user.PRINCIPAL_ID = dr.GetInt32(dr.GetOrdinal("PRINCIPAL_ID"));
            user.AA_USER_FK = dr.GetInt32(dr.GetOrdinal("AA_USER_FK"));
            user.FIRST_NAME = dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("FIRST_NAME"));
            user.LAST_NAME = dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("LAST_NAME"));
            user.USER_NAME = dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("USER_NAME"));
            user.EMAIL_ADDRESS = dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("EMAIL_ADDRESS"));
            user.ACTIVE = dr.GetBoolean(dr.GetOrdinal("ACTIVE"));
            user.LV_USER_ROLE_FK = dr.GetInt32(dr.GetOrdinal("LV_USER_ROLE_FK"));
            user.USER_ROLE = dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("USER_ROLE"));
            user.CREATED_BY = dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("CREATED_BY"));
            user.CREATED_SYSDATE = dr.GetDateTime(dr.GetOrdinal("CREATED_SYSDATE"));
        }
        dr.Close();
    }
}
```

I have ensure the column name is correct however I am now stuck at this new found exception.

[image: Image showing exception]

Has anyone seen this behavior before.  My apologies if I am overlooking and obvious but could use an extra set of eyes on this.

LV_USER_ROLES Table

[image: LV_USER_ROLES]

USERS Table

[image: USERS Table]

Comment: you can share details of the exception? (ViewDetails)

Comment: For one thing, use `WHERE (@active = 2 OR ACTIVE = @active)` and get rid of the dynamic SQL headache. But use `NULL` instead of `2` for unspecified because that's what `NULL` is for, so `WHERE (@active IS NULL OR ACTIVE = @active)` . This procedure is far more complex than it needs to be because of the unnecessary dynamic SQL.

Comment: Also, you add a `@whereClause` parameter that's not used so you can remove that line. Thank goodness it's not, too, because that's the definition of SQL injection. The `@whereClause` variable declared within the stored procedure is entirely different.

Comment: What's the point of using parameters if you're still constructing a dynamic SQL string? The new dynamic SQL string is as vulnerable to SQL injection and conversion errors as if you built it in C#. At least if you did so in C# it would be easier to see what's going on

Comment: If someone entered `'; DROP TABLE Users; --` in the search field you'd lose the table. The C# Format function would generate `"USER_NAME = ''; DROP TABLE Users; --`". The only thing that saves the app is that there's no `@whereClause` parameter. Are you sure you're executing the correct stored procedure?

Comment: You could still use dynamic SQL, just pass the parameter all the way through `EXEC sp_executesql @sqlCmd, N'@active int', @active = @active` Also your reader needs a `using`. Either way, it looks like you are calling the wrong stored procedure with the wrong parameter

Comment: Don't use [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Comment: Thanks Charlieface; the result of having 2 similiar named usp's.  Changed the usp that was beng called and the my index out of range exception went away.

Answer (score 0):

Charlieface's comment resolved the exception.  In this database there is 2 similiar named usp's and I was calling the wrong one.

Comment: Hi, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider accepting it as answer to change its status to Answered. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)